# How to extract the dictionary from list of dictionary with condition

Tags: python, dictionary

How to extract from the json with condition

I have  a list of dictionary. I need extract some of the dictionary with some conditions

- If for cross field I need "AND" condition
- for same field array I need to OR condition

1. I need to search `subject` which is `Physics` or `Accounting` this is array of fields(OR) statement

   AND
2. I need to search `type` is `Permanent` or `GUEST` condition this is array of fields(OR) statement

   AND
3. I need to search `Location` is `NY`(&) condition

```
test = [{'id':1,'name': 'A','subject': ['Maths','Accounting'],'type':'Contract', 'Location':'NY'},
      { 'id':2,'name': 'AB','subject': ['Physics','Engineering'],'type':'Permanent','Location':'NY'},
    {'id':3,'name': 'ABC','subject': ['Maths','Engineering'],'type':'Permanent','Location':'NY'},
{'id':4,'name':'ABCD','subject': ['Physics','Engineering'],'type':['Contract','Guest'],'Location':'NY'}]
```

Expected out is id `[{ 'id':2,'name': 'AB','subject': ['Physics','Engineering'],'type':'Permanent','Location':'NY'},{'id':4,'name':'ABCD','subject': ['Physics','Engineering'],'type':['Contract','Guest'],'Location':'NY'}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is mostly that your data is not uniform, sometimes it's strings, sometimes it's list. Let's try:

```
# turns the values into set for easy comparison
def get_set(d,field):
    return {d[field]} if isinstance(d[field], str) else set(d[field])
    
# we use this to filter
def validate(d):
    # the three lines below corresponds to the three conditions listed
    return get_set(d,'subject').intersection({'Physics','Accounting'}) and \
           get_set(d,'type').intersection({'Permanent', 'Guest'}) and \
           get_set(d,'Location')=={'NY'}

result = [d for d in test if validate(d)]
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 2,
  'name': 'AB',
  'subject': ['Physics', 'Engineering'],
  'type': 'Permanent',
  'Location': 'NY'},
 {'id': 4,
  'name': 'ABCD',
  'subject': ['Physics', 'Engineering'],
  'type': ['Contract', 'Guest'],
  'Location': 'NY'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following simple approach with a nested if clause solves the issue. The `and` condition is done via the nested `if` and the `or` conditions is simply done via `or`.

The `in` operator works for string values and list values, therefore it can be used interchangeably and results in the expected out. BUT this approach expects that there are no specific subjects like `XYZ Accounting`.

```py
result = []

for elem in test:
    
    # Check Location
    if elem['Location'] == 'NY':
    
        # Check subject
        subject = elem['subject']
        if ('Accounting' in subject) or ('Physics' in subject):
        
            # Check type
            elem_type = elem['type']
            if ('Permanent' in elem_type) or ('Guest' in elem_type):
                # Add element to result, because all conditions are true
                result.append(elem)
```